# Filling fixed sized array with either integer 1 or 2 to make a sum X

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum

Let's say I have a fixed sized array. I want to fill the array with either 1s or 2s so that all element sums up to X.

Example:

- Required sum = 12
- Array size = 7

Possible combinations:

```
array( 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2 ) // sums to 12

array( 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ) // sums to 12
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Find the number of 2's in the array, this number is:

  ```
  #2's = X - array_size
  ```
- Chose <strike>random</strike> arbitrary `#2's` elements (for example the first elements), and
  give them the value 2, the rest of the elements will get the value 1.

**Note:** it is easy to see that if `X < array_size` or `X> 2*array_size` there is no solution to the problem (and obviously the above algorithm will fail)